# Unable to find column with logical name - hibernate exception when using @OneToMany and @JoinColumn

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have got two entities in my application Orders and Products (one-to-many association). I am aiming to set up a unidirectional OneToMany relationship in Order entity (I'm aware that it is not the best solution, however this is a business requirement). The database schema is generated by Liquibase and validated by Hibernate. Entities have been simplified for the sake of clarity. Database is Postgres.

Although the schema is created correctly, Hibernate throws an exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.cfg.RecoverableException: Unable to find column with logical name: productId in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(orders) and its related supertables and secondary tables
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3JoinColumn.checkReferencedColumnsType(Ejb3JoinColumn.java:844) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.createSyntheticPropertyReference(BinderHelper.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindCollectionSecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1740) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: productId in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(orders) and its related supertables and secondary tables
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3JoinColumn.checkReferencedColumnsType(Ejb3JoinColumn.java:839) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
```

To prove that the schema is generated appropriately, I replaced *@OneToMany* annotation with *@ManyToOne* and **it works fine**! All of the sudden, Hibernate is able to find the column. After that I began assuming that there is some kind of bug in Hibernate...

Does anyone have an idea, how to solve this issue?

My code looks as follows:

**Order.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long orderId;

    @Column
    private String clientName;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "productIdFK", referencedColumnName = "productId")
    private List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

**Product.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long productId;

    @Column
    private String name;
}
```

**Liquibase script**

```
{
  "databaseChangeLog": [
    {
      "changeSet": {
        "id": "Create PRODUCT table",
        "author": "me",
        "changes": [
          {
            "createTable": {
              "tableName": "products",
              "columns": [
                {
                  "column": {
                    "name": "productId",
                    "type": "bigint",
                    "constraints": {
                      "nullable": false,
                      "unique": true,
                      "primaryKey": true
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "column": {
                    "name": "name",
                    "type": "varchar(250)",
                    "constraints": {
                      "nullable": true,
                      "unique": false
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "createTable": {
              "tableName": "orders",
              "columns": [
                {
                  "column": {
                    "name": "orderId",
                    "type": "bigint",
                    "constraints": {
                      "nullable": false,
                      "unique": true,
                      "primaryKey": true
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "column": {
                    "name": "clientName",
                    "type": "varchar(250)",
                    "constraints": {
                      "nullable": true,
                      "unique": false
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "column": {
                    "name": "productIdFK",
                    "type": "bigint",
                    "constraints": {
                      "nullable": true,
                      "unique": false
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Snippet from liquibase script generating relationships**

```
{
            "addForeignKeyConstraint": {
              "constraintName": "fk_product_order",
              "baseColumnNames": "productIdFK",
              "baseTableName": "orders",
              "referencedColumnNames": "productId",
              "referencedTableName": "products"
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "orderId", referencedColumnName = "productId")// try orderId
private List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Once you try this
hope this will work out

change to this in **Order.java**

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy= "order")
private List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
```

add this in **Product.java**

```
@ManyToOne
@JsonIgnore
private Order order;
```

let me know

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a solution - in this case Hibernate requires a column with foreign key in products table (and I need it in orders, therefore I use @JoinColumn in Orders entity) ```SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing column [order_orderId] in table [products] ```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this too.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "order")
private List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
```

along with this in Product.java

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "productId",
        foreignKey = @ForeignKey(
                name = "product_id_fk"))
private Order order;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let's clarify what 1 is and what many are at your schema. As Order has a reference to Product that means many Orders might be related to the same Product, mightn't they? A bidirectional relationship is usually preferred but you need the unidirectional one, it should be something like

```
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long orderId;

    @Column
    private String clientName;
}
```

and

```
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long productId;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "productIdFK", referencedColumnName = "productId")
    private List<Order> orderList = new ArrayList<>();
```

}